# スクレイピング出力で文字化け

Tags: node.js, csv, web-scraping, 文字化け

スクレイピング結果をcsvに出力したところ、文字化けがおこります。
出力時に文字化けを起こさないようにするには、どのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか？
宜しくお願いします。

```
const {createObjectCsvWriter} = require('csv-writer');
const client = require('cheerio-httpcli');

const csvFilePath = '00000data.csv'
const csvWriter = createObjectCsvWriter({
    path: csvFilePath,
    header: [
        {id: 'name', title: 'NAME'}
    ],
    encoding:'utf8',
    append :false,
});

const players = [];

client.fetch('http://npb.jp/bis/teams/rst_g.html',)
    .then((result) => {
        // テキストを配列に格納
        result.$('.rosterRegister').each(function (idx) {
            const $player = result.$(this).text();
            players.push({name: $player});
        });
        // csvファイルに書き込み
        csvWriter.writeRecords(players)
            .then(() => {
                console.log('...書き込み完了');
            });

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        console.log('終了！');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「文字化けがおこる」というのは何をもって判断していますか？
ファイル作成処理でのエンコーディング指定は`utf8`になっています。

```
const csvWriter = createObjectCsvWriter({
    <<途中省略>>
    encoding:'utf8',
    append :false,
});
```

例えば出来たcsvファイルをテキストエディタ等で見ている場合は、ファイルオープン時のエンコーディングをutf-8に指定すれば良いでしょう。

Excel等でオープンしている場合は、ファイル作成時にファイルの先頭にutf-8のBOMを書いておく必要があるでしょう。
こんな記事を参考に。
[BOMやBlobを理解してJavaScriptでCSVを出力する](https://qiita.com/megadreams14/items/b4521308d5be65f0c544)